# How to use a package for node in angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, package

I am doing a school project to teach us the basics of a bittorrent client. I decided to use `node-torrent` found here https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-torrent to help me. It is made for node, I am using angular 2.

I want to know if it is possible to implement this in an angular 2 web application and if not, how I would otherwise use it. I am pretty new to angular. I have attempted to just follow the tutorial which has us using this bit of code:

```
var Client = require('node-torrent');
var client = new Client({logLevel: 'DEBUG'});
var torrent = client.addTorrent('a.torrent');

// when the torrent completes, move it's files to another area 
torrent.on('complete', function() {
    console.log('complete!');
    torrent.files.forEach(function(file) {
        var newPath = '/new/path/' + file.path;
        fs.rename(file.path, newPath);
        // while still seeding need to make sure file.path points to the right place 
        file.path = newPath;
    });
});
```

But the problem is I have no idea where to implement this. Also, usually there is a way to add this to my package.json in angular 2 with a npm install, but there is no indication of how to do that. I am assuming I have to download it?

Comment: Are you using express to serve? You need to create a route to an endpoint in express (e.g. `/torrent/`) and POST to it the torrent link you want to add (angular will POST, express will use the route `/torrent/` and read the request from angular, then process the code you reference here and return the info back to angular. This is pretty basic server - client interaction. [This tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular) talks more about creating apps that work between angular and express

Comment: thank you!! I looked up a tutorial on express (I had no idea what that was) and it worked perfectly!